# Excel SUMIFs with multiple conditions, including day inequalities in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, sumifs

The Excel function **SUMIFS** supports calculation based on multiple criteria, including day inequalities, as follows

```
values_to_sum, criteria_range_n, condition_n, .., criteria_range_n, condition_n
```

##### Example

Input - tips per person per day, multiple entries per person per day allowed

```
date        person  tip
02/03/2022  X       10
05/03/2022  X       30
05/03/2022  Y       20
08/03/2022  X       12
08/03/2022  X       8
```

Output - sum per selected person per day

```
date        X_sum_per_day
01/03/2022  0
02/03/2022  10
03/03/2022  0
04/03/2022  0
05/03/2022  30
06/03/2022  0
07/03/2022  0
08/03/2022  20
09/03/2022  0
10/03/2022  0
```

[image]

Can this be implemented in pandas and calculated as series for an input range of days? Cumulative would be presumably just application of cumsum() but the initial **sum based on multiple criteria** is tricky, especially if to be **concise**.

##### Code

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['02-03-2022 00:00:00',
                            '05-03-2022 00:00:00',
                            '05-03-2022 00:00:00',
                            '08-03-2022 00:00:00',
                            '08-03-2022 00:00:00'],
                   'person': ['X', 'X', 'Y', 'X', 'X'],
                   'tip': [10, 30, 20, 12, 8]},
                   index = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4])

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.date_range(start='2022-03-01', end='2022-03-10')})
temp = df[df['person'] == 'X'].groupby(['date']).sum().reset_index()
df2['X_sum'] = df2['date'].map(temp.set_index('date')['tip']).fillna(0)
```

The above seems kinda hacky and not as simple to reason about as Excel SUMIFS. Additional conditions would also be a hassle (e.g. sum where country = X, company = Y, person = Z).

Any idea for alternative implementation?

Comment: do you mind explaining the logic for an Excel noob like me?

Comment: Imagine 2 tables in Excel: one with continuous date range and another with tip records (tip, person, day). Applying sumifs to first table enables to sum tip values from all there rows where conditions are met (e.g. name = X, day = date or in case of cumulation day <= date). Adding printscreen in original post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you want to filter the person `X` then `groupby` day and sum the tips, finally `reindex` the missing days:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], dayfirst=True)

out = (df[df['person'].eq('X')]
 .groupby('date')['tip'].sum()
 .reindex(pd.date_range(start='2022-03-01', end='2022-03-10'),
          fill_value=0)
 .reset_index()
)
```

output:

```
       index  tip
0 2022-03-01    0
1 2022-03-02   10
2 2022-03-03    0
3 2022-03-04    0
4 2022-03-05   30
5 2022-03-06    0
6 2022-03-07    0
7 2022-03-08   20
8 2022-03-09    0
9 2022-03-10    0
```